# Swipe between ListView items (like with ViewPager) in Android 4.0+

Tags: android, swipe

I have an app which supports Android 4.0+ (i.e. android:minSdkVersion="14"). I've created a ListView and when clicking on its item the app moves to an Activity with single Fragment in it. I want to implement swiping between this items (like in Gmail app between conversations), but the only approach I see is using the ViewPager, which is a part of Compatibility library. So maybe there is some way to implement this behavior without using support libraries (which also means changing Activities to FragmentActivities, FragmentManagers to SupportFragmentManagers, android.app.Fragment to Fragment from support library and so on).

Can I avoid this somehow or should I use ViewPager and support library even if minsdkversion="22"?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think using viewpager will cause you any problem because viewpager doesn't require minsdkversion = 22.

Comment: But it requires using android-support library, which is for Android v2 that i don't need if my app has "14" or "22" as mininum sdk version.

Comment: Well, viewpager is the simplest way and i bet gmail app is using it. you can always implement your own viewpager-like viewgroup, but i wouldn't suggest that... if you need a feature of the support library, then include it in your project, it's the shortest path and i don't see any drawback at least from your question.